# DMS replication task getting destoyed and created again with each terrafrom apply

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-dms

I have a DMS replication task in Terraform. I haven't set the argument `start_replication_task = true` so when I do terraform apply my replication task gets created and will be in Ready state. I want to start it manually. After starting it manually it goes to Running state. But when I do the terraform apply again. It switches back to ready state. I want it to be in running state from the subsequent terraform apply. Basically, I want to check if the task exists or not and if the task doesn't exist It should get created and stay in the Ready state. If the task already exists, I want to know the status. If the task status is in running I want it to be switch to the running state after subsequent terraform apply.

The below is my replication task code

```
resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "dms_rds_to_s3_replication_task" {
  migration_type = "full-load-and-cdc"
  replication_instance_arn = aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_replication_instance.replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id = "${var.common_vars.env}-replication-task"
  source_endpoint_arn = aws_dms_endpoint.dms_source_endpoint.endpoint_arn
  target_endpoint_arn = aws_dms_s3_endpoint.dms_target_endpoint.endpoint_arn
  replication_task_settings = data.template_file.replication_task_settings_template.rendered
  table_mappings = data.template_file.table_mapping_rules_template.rendered
  # start_replication_task = local.start_replication_task

  depends_on = [
    aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_replication_instance,
    aws_dms_s3_endpoint.dms_target_endpoint,
    aws_dms_endpoint.dms_source_endpoint
    
  ]
}

data "template_file" "replication_task_settings_template" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/replication-task-settings.json")}"
}

data "template_file" "table_mapping_rules_template" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/table-mapping-rules.json")}"

  vars = {
    db_name = var.rds_details.db_name
  }
}
```